# Select distinct values from a matrix column

Tags: add-on, matrix, pixelandtonic

I've got a matrix column with 110 rows but only 11 values (each value in 11 times). Is there a way to query the distinct values in that column rather than returning all the results?

Comment: In a front-end template using the Matrix field's tag? or via an SQL query?

Comment: Matrix field tag. I can do a manual query, just trying to stay in EE tags if possible.

Comment: If you know which rows your values sit in you could use the row_id parameter e.g. {my_matrix_field_name row_id="1|2|3"}

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with a Matrix tag, but you could use Stash to set a list of the Matrix rows, then get the `unique` values only.

https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#unique---yes--no-

**matrix set_list**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" entry_id="123"}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="blog_related_entries" parse_tags="yes" save="yes" scope="site"}
        {blog_related}
            {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
        {/blog_related}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}   
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**get_list with unique="yes"**

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="blog_related_entries" unique="yes"}
    {item_title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Granted, this doesn't really save you on performance since all of the Matrix rows are pulled any way.